# IronPython fails to load dependency possibly due to name conflict

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ironpython, add-references-dialog

I am experiencing an issue with IronPython when referencing an assembly that has the same name (part before the *.dll*) as another file in the same directory.

For example, if *Foo.xml* and *Foo.Xml.dll* are in the same directory, the directory has been appended to *sys.path* and an attempt is made to reference the assembly *Foo.Xml*:

```
clr.AddReference("Foo.Xml")
```

the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly Foo.Xml
   at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReference(CodeContext context, Object[] references)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke1Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Hosting.PythonCommandLine.<>c__DisplayClass1.<RunOneInteraction>b__0()
```

Now, this can be avoided by simply including the *.dll* extension in the `AddReference()` call.

However, when the ambiguity occurs for a dependency of the assembly being referenced, this is no longer in your control. For example, let's say the assembly *Foo.dll* depends on *Foo.Xml.dll*. When IronPython attempts to resolve this dependency internally, it will encounter the aforementioned name conflict and fail. The error is slightly less verbose, but the issue appears to be the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] Could not load file or assembly 'Foo.Xml, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

In both cases, changing the name of the *Foo.xml* file is the difference between successfully loading the *Foo.Xml.dll* assembly and failure.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone have a workaround? A better approach?

Comment: I will take a look at it later.